# Merging arbitrarily nested dictionaries, maintaining keys, and putting results with the same key in a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

This is my input:

```
dict1 = { 'home': 'Documents'}
dict2 = { 'home': {'Documents': 'projects'}}
dict3 = {'projects': 'test.py'}
dict4 = {'projects': 'test2.py'}
dict5 = {'Documents': 'old_memes'}
dict6 = {'old_memes': 'me_gusta.jpg'}
dict7 = {'old_memes': 'fml.jpg'}
```

My goal is to have an output of a single dictionary, like this:

```
final_dict = {'home': 
                      {'Documents':
                                   [
                                    {'projects': ['test.py','test2.py']},
                                    {'old_memes':['me_gusta.jpg','fml.jpg']}
                                   ]
                       }
              }
```

I searched around, but couldn't find nothing that do this. I tried using `defaultdict` but it didn't work either. If this is not possible with dictionaties, can you point me another data structure that can do this(and be converted to a JSON)?

Comment: The nesting in `dict2` makes things more complicated. We don't have the guarantee of flat dictionaries as input? And what about the ordering? Will it always be top-down?

Comment: @aryamccarthy we do not have the guarantee of flat dictionaries, because my goal is to create a merger that's flexible. Yes, it will always be top down.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? We're not a code-writing service; you'll get help if you provide a [mcve].